# Remove Google Account From android device in marshmallow?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, google-account

I am working with google account and i want to remove all the logged in account from device with the help of my application and i did it with this line of code

```
 private void signOutGmail() {
        AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
        Account[] accounts = am.getAccounts();
        if (accounts.length > 0) {
            Account accountToRemove = accounts[0];
            am.removeAccount(accountToRemove, null, null);
        }
    }
```

But when i run my application in marshmallow i got an error of Security Exception and my application get crashed is there any solution to remove gmail accounts from device programmatically in marshmallow and up.

This is my exception:

```
02-27 12:25:11.386 14485-14485/com.example.deletedemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.deletedemo, PID: 14485
                                                                         java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10145 cannot remove accounts of type: com.google
                                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
                                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
                                                                             at android.accounts.IAccountManager$Stub$Proxy.removeAccount(IAccountManager.java:915)
                                                                             at android.accounts.AccountManager$6.doWork(AccountManager.java:844)
                                                                             at android.accounts.AccountManager$BaseFutureTask.startTask(AccountManager.java:2024)
                                                                             at android.accounts.AccountManager$Future2Task.start(AccountManager.java:2079)
                                                                             at android.accounts.AccountManager.removeAccount(AccountManager.java:841)
                                                                             at com.example.deletedemo.MainActivity.signOutGmail(MainActivity.java:134)
                                                                             at com.example.deletedemo.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:68)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Please Help!
Thank You!!

Answer (score 1):

You need these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER"/>
```

EDIT: For marshmallow, request permission at runtime.

Comment: Account manager gives me permission only granted to system apps exception.

Comment: @RishabhMahatha request permission at runtime.

Comment: Can you please send me a demo for that?